# Create standalone library for Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspect

I have a spring boot microservices project with different services , dao implementations and endpoints. 
I have created an custom AOP annotation @LogMethod to log method start and end using @Around Advice. All the logger that are generated are through the advice method.

Now, all this is in one project, but to make this annotation as reusable in different projects, can anyone guide me how can i seperate out all the aspect implementation (custom aop annotation , advice, pointcut, logger service that generates log statement of method call and end. Note : in this aspect @Service , @Autowried annotation have been used) into alltogether a different library let say log-method-lib.

Comment: create new project with custom aspects. Package it as a jar. Include library jar as a dependency of your microservices.

Comment: How do u include ? like setting a path locally, ? can u share some example

Comment: Will it be okay if i also include spring dependencies as well in it ? an package it as jar ?

Comment: Include like maven/gradle dependency. You have to include spring dependencies to your library jar, if you will not include them, then jar will not compile.

Comment: <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.runtime.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.runtime.version}</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>

Comment: I have added above dependencies

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nobody can help you if you don't share your code. You are asking for refactoring help, after all. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and ask accordingly. then others can help you. As it is now, the question is not suitable for StackOverflow and will rather attract close votes than answers.